# MySQL insert from a textarea to multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I have a simple form which is a textarea and I need to insert each lines in my textarea into a different rows in MySQL.

HTML code:

```
<html>
<form method="POST" action="insert.php">
<textarea name="url" rows="10" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
</html>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
      die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('insert', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
     die ('Can\'t use this database : ' . mysql_error());
}
$textarea = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url']);
$array = explode("\n", $textarea);
$i=0;
$value = trim($array[$i]);
if (!empty($value)) {
     foreach ($array as $value) {
          mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES ('{$array[$i]}')") or       die(mysql_error());
          $i++;
     }
}
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Currently I'll store textarea in ONE row when I submit my form. Could you please help me with that.

Comment: What happens with this? I would get rid of `{$array[$i]}` and all `$i` references, just use `$value`. I also would use parameterized queries and an updated driver (PDO or mysqli).

Comment: What do you see in `var_dump($array)`?

Comment: If the rest of the stackoverflow population finds out you're not using PDO, you're going to hear about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$text = trim($_POST['textareaname']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r chars

foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    // Your sql Query here with $line as the string.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$textarea = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url']);
$array = explode("\n", $textarea);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES ('".$value."')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```