# Multiline text box to multi record insert MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a requirement for a new page on my website, which I am struggling with.
At a very basic level I need to have the following input boxes on the page:

```
LOCATION
DATE
REGISTRATION(S)
```

the location will be a single line e.g. - `Manchester Airport`
the date will also be a single line e.g. - `2018-05-10`
the registrations could be from a single line upto 2,000 lines e.g.-

```
G-TUIA
G-TUIB
G-TDCS
A6-AAA
B-LRP
CS-DSQ
```

What I need to do, is to get the page to input a single record into the database.spottings table for each of the lines in the text box.
i.e. Each line will be preceded by the location and date fields, then each row will have appended to it a registration from the REGISTRATION box.
So we would have from the above dataset = (Comma denotes the end of that field).

```
Manchester Airport,2018-05-10,G-TUIA,
Manchester Airport,2018-05-10,G-TUIB,
Manchester Airport,2018-05-10,G-TDCS,
Manchester Airport,2018-05-10,A6-AAA,
Manchester Airport,2018-05-10,B-LRP,
Manchester Airport,2018-05-10,CS-DSQ,
```

I have been fully able to input a single record per page, but if you have several thousand needing to be inputted, it would be very resource intensive.

Comment: First question: What have you tried in PHP? If you prepare a statement you can insert over and over and over with it very quickly by binding in different values. PDO makes this almost trivial.

Comment: I have tried doing this by the n2blr tag but that just adds line breaks in the field when its pulled back out of the database into the PHP page, and it inputs it as a single field. the registrations obviously hits a char limit (10) so cuts off the remaining ones inputted.

Comment: `explode("\n", $_POST['inputfield'])` will split the input into lines.

Comment: In PHP, you can use explode to turn the multi-line input into an array. Then you can loop through the array, inserting the records.

Comment: `nl2br` is for HTML, not for this. Just use `explode` as Barmar points out.

Comment: Are you sure this is the best database design to hold this information? I am not so sure!!

Comment: ahh right super something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711880/mysql-insert-from-a-textarea-to-multiple-rows - thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: The table is a simple one- has only ID,uname,date,location,registration in it. this will link out to other tables within the database for the aircraft information.

Answer (score 0):

```
list($location, $date, $registration) = explode("\n", $_POST['inputname'])
```

Replace `inputname` with the actual name of the `<textarea>` used in the form.

But I wonder why you're doing this as a multiline textarea instead of separate input fields for each field.

Comment: Hi, I have users that are particularly lazy. they can have upto 2,000 registrations they want to insert on a daily basis so for them to input each one into a text box on its own can be a pain for them (bless) so If they can cut and paste the aircraft registration into the text box as a list and click on "go" they would be much happier!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to add to your question a description of which programming languages (or frameworks?) you're writing this with.  As far as the overhead of entering a few thousand records - some APIs (like Java's JDBC) support the notion of batch inserts, which would reduce the overhead associated with the set of inserts being batched together.  Turning the values of the airport column into codes might also reduce overhead during insert, by turning the varchar strings into ints?